# How to make Appbar transparent and with no padding in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I get rid of the padding separating the toolbar from the content?

I would like to achieve the same result like the picture below

**Expectation:**

[image: A codepen example: https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/qBbVNWG]

**What I got:**
[image: My result]

This is my **App.vue** file

```
     <v-app>
       <app-navigation></app-navigation>
    
        <v-main>
          <v-content class="ma-0 pa-0">
            <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-center" width="900">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300"/>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300"/>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/300"/>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300"/>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300"/>
            </div>
          </v-content>
   
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
```

And this is my **AppNavigation** file - basically, the toolbar component:

```
<v-toolbar color="transparent" flat>

  <router-link to="/">
    <v-toolbar-title class="pr-10"> {{ appTitle }} </v-toolbar-title>
  </router-link>

  <v-btn class="hidden-sm-and-down" text rounded to="/hello"> HELLO </v-btn>
  <v-btn class="hidden-sm-and-down" text rounded to="/hello"> HELLO </v-btn>
  <v-btn class="hidden-sm-and-down" text rounded to="/about"> About </v-btn>

  <v-spacer class="hidden-sm-and-down" ></v-spacer>
    <v-btn class="hidden-sm-and-down" outlined rounded to="/sign-up"> SIGN UP</v-btn>
    <v-btn class="hidden-sm-and-down" outlined rounded to="/log-in"> LOG IN </v-btn>

</v-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `absolute` and `width="100%"` to the `<v-toolbar/>`.

```html
<v-toolbar flat color="transparent" absolute width="100%">
...
</v-toolbar>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-goldstine-6s3tm?file=/src/components/AppNavigation.vue:48-70):

[image]